# Selecting ID in while statement PHP

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I'm attempting to make a function that will allow users to delete posts they have left. Basically I'm trying to select an ID and then pass it off to another function to delete it. The current code is deleting every comment, not just the comment linked to the ID like I'm attempting to.

Here are the table values

```
Table eventUpdates
ID - unique ID. Trying to use this value to delete the post
eventID - references an eventID from another table
eventReply - the "message" or response
eventUserID -ID of the user posting the message
username -username of the person
eventTimestamp -timestamp
```

So, currently every response is being deleted. I can't get it to delete just the ID that I send.

```
<table border ="1">
<?
$eventUpdates = mysql_query($sql);
while ($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($eventUpdates)) {  
        echo $updateID;
                echo '<tr><td>';
                    echo $list['username'],"</br>", $list['eventTimestamp'],'<br/>';
                        if($list['eventUserID'] == $userid){ //used for deleting posts. Checks the session to make sure it's the user who made the post
                                ?>
                                <form method="post">
                                <input type="submit" name="deleteUpdate" value="Delete Update">
                                </form>
                                <?
                                if(isset($_POST['deleteUpdate'])){
                                    $updateID = $list['ID'];
                                    $delete = new postprocessing;
                                    $delete->deleteEventUpdate($updateID);
                                    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=main.php">';
                                }
                        }
                        echo '</td><td>';
                        echo $list['eventReply'];
                        echo '</td></tr>';
}
```

Here is the function used to delete it

```
function deleteEventUpdate($ID){
   mysql_query("delete from eventUpdates where ID = '$ID'");
}
```

Comment: Well this will delete all comments of course. Since you are looping through the entire list, each time u loop, it deletes all the comments for that event. Which would therefore delete all comments at the end of the loop

Comment: I tried the same thing outside of the loop, but then I realized it doesn't "know" which ID I'm trying to select.

Comment: well i guess thats it, sending a blank ID will delete everything :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you haven't specified the ID you want to delete in the post array, so every comment they created "matches" the deletion criteria. The `$_POST` array looks like:

$_POST = array('deleteUpdate'='Delete Update');

so when you're looping through the list of events, every comment that the user 'owns' (`$list['eventUserID'] == $userid`) matches the criteria "`isset($_POST['deleteUpdate'])`":

You need to include a hidden input with the ID the specific comment you want to delete and match against it as well:

```
<form method="post">
<input type="submit" name="deleteUpdate" value="Delete Update">
<input name='post_id' value="<?php echo $list['ID'];?>" type='hidden' />
</form>
```

and then in the loop:

```
if(isset($_POST['deleteUpdate']) && isset($_POST['post_id']) && $_POST['post_id']==$list['ID']){...
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot. It's been a long day, using a hidden input didn't even come to mind. Thanks for the help!